# Can you do a Stop Command during when the discord bot is functioning a command

Tags: python, discord.py

here is the code

I also need help making a loop command and a quantity command

any ideas?

it is much longer in my proper code.

```
@client.command()
async def startspam(ctx, message=None):
    await ctx.send(message)
    await ctx.send(message)
    await ctx.send(message)
    await ctx.send(message)
    await ctx.send(message)
    await ctx.send(message)
    await ctx.send(message)

@client.command()
async def stopspam(ctx):
   await ctx.send('stopping...')
   end.startspam()
   await ctx.send('Stopped!')
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first off, just repeating your message in the code is terrible practice. You can use a while loop and global variables to achieve your goal.

```
@bot.command()
async def startspam(ctx, *, message):
    global spambool
    spambool = True
    while spambool is True:
        await ctx.send(message)
        await asyncio.sleep(2)


@bot.command()
async def stopspam(ctx):
    global spambool
    spambool = False
    await ctx.send("stopped")
```

You can adjust the asyncio.sleep to your liking or leave it out but be aware of rate limits.

Comment: It says Asyncio not defined

Comment: I fixed it. I had to delete last like in StartSpam. btw ty

Comment: To use `asyncio.sleep` you first need to `import asyncio`. Btw if the answer helped please mark it as accepted so others can see the question is not open anymore. Glad it works for you.